# Set default country in rubys geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-geocoder

I am using this great gem 'geocoder' by alexreisner with nominatim as geolocation service.

Because the service of my web application is only available for a specific country I was wondering, if it is possbile to set a default country or region?

By setting a default country I am hoping to decrease multiple (false) hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a hardcoded Country in your model, such as:

```
geocoded_by :address

def address
  [street, city, state, 'Belgium'].compact.join(', ')
end
```

Remove/add fields from that array as required.